# I am trying to deploy my dash app but I am taking in local txt files that contain my data. How can I do this?

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I am following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@austinlasseter/how-to-deploy-a-simple-plotly-dash-app-to-heroku-622a2216eb73

The only difference, however, is the data that my app.py file analyzes comes from a local text file that is in csv format. My app works fine when testing it locally. It is when I deploy it to Heroku that an error comes. Is it not possible to take in a local txt file and deploy the app? First time trying these tools/packages so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text file is local, how does your heroku deployment access that file? It's only local to your development environment, not your heroku environment. If you have a CSV file, then you could probably store that data in a SQL database and while your app runs in deployment, it queries the DB and pulls out the data you need.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions for where to store the data? I'd prefer not using SQL.

Comment: You could use some form of [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Types_and_examples) database. When it comes to storing data for a web app to access, though, it's pretty much going to be some kind of database that ultimately stores it. Can you tell me what about SQL makes you not want to use it? Maybe I can offer a better recommendation based on that.

Comment: Ah I understand. My preference would be to keep the data in a .txt because the data will be updated frequently through another python script but if that's not possible then perhaps i'll have to use SQL.